# Best way create multiple task with HttpClent request

Tags: c#, task, httpclient

I want to create a loop to test a web client. I have a HttpClient and I want to send 100 request, one every 3 seconds.

My function to send request is (`async Task` because of the `PostAsync`):

```
private static async Task SendRequestAsync(HttpClient client, int taskID)
{
    try
    {
        String xmlData = GetXmlData();
        var content = new StringContent(xmlData);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("sendRequest.ashx?RequestId=" + taskID, content);

        // write response in a file
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

Now I want to :

- create a loop with 100 iteration
- call the method in each iteration
- wait for all task after the loop

I wrote a piece of code. This is working but I have a `TaskCanceledException` after some iteration (not always the same) :

```
List<Task> listTask = new List<Task>();
using (HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(urlRequest)
    };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

    int cpt = 0;
    while (cpt < 100)
    {
        cpt++;
        int tmp = cpt;
        listTask.Add(Task.Run(() => SendRequestAsync(client, tmp)));

        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray());
```

What cause the `TaskCanceledException` and how can I fix this ?

**EDIT**

After some investigations, I saw that I have a `System.ObjectDisposedException` in an object `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream` but I can't identify the thread throwing this exception.

Is there a way that this exception come from my `HttpClientHandler handler` ? In that case, how can I recreate the object to continue the loop ?

Comment: Why do have `Thread.Sleep(3000);` in your code? You already has `Task.WaitAll(listTask.ToArray());`.

Comment: @Sham the sleep is because i'm testing the client, I want to send a request every 3 seconds. Request take 2 to 10 seconds. The final wait all is there because I always have 5 or more unfinished task when loop is over (when loop ends without exception).

Comment: Eliminate the `Task.Run(...)`, just do `listTask.Add(SendRequestAsync(client, tmp));`

Comment: This code my produce errors if the requests take longer than 3 seconds. because the handler gets disposed to early. But I am not sure, if the HttpClient can operate even if the handler is disposed. Maybe you should try to move the Wait() into the using() block.

Comment: @JosefBiehler I moved the `Task.WaitAll` and eliminated the `Task.Run` but I still have a `TaskCanceledException`. With a try/catch on `client.PostAsync` can I have mode details ? Actually the innerexception is null

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `Task.WaitAll(listTask);` and remove `Thread.Sleep(3000)`

Additionaly you can consider using Task Parallel Library particularly Parrell.ForEach

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` is already there. With a `Parrell.ForEach`, tasks are started synchronously or asynchronously ?